# Implementing bound method using descriptor

Tags: python, descriptor

My question is related to bound method object, more specifically I am trying to imitate the same behavior that functions (which are essentially descriptors) present.

Let me first put here my understanding of how class_instance.function() works

```
class D(object):
    def dfunc(self):
        ...
 
d=D()
d.dfunc() # will call D.__dict__['dfunc'].__get__(d,D)()

# gives a bound method which can be used directly
a=D.__dict__['dfunc'].__get__(d,D) 
a() # works as d.D()
```

Does Python call `D.__dict__['dfunc'] (d)`, in case when `type(dfunc)` is function and `type(d).__dict__['dfunc'].__get__(d, type(d))` if x is a class instance?

Now coming to how I am trying to create a bound object using closure:

```
class E(object):
    def __get__(self,obj,cls):
    
        def returned(*args):
            print(obj.__dict__)
        return returned

class F(object):
    e = E()
    y = 9

f = F()
f.fvar = 9 # putting something in instances __dict__
a = f.e # will call the __get__ function of F and return a closure
a() # works and produces instance specific result -> {'fvar': 9}, just like a bound method
```

Now the main question,
when I did `a = D.__dict__['dfunc'].__get__(d,D)` type(a) was bound method, but when I implement it `type(a)` is function; is there a way to return bound object from user-defined descriptor?

Is there any better way to implement a function like descriptor?
Please correct me if I have gotten something fundamentally incorrect in my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return a method instead, you can create one from the function object together with the arguments passed to `__get__`:

```
import types

class E(object):
    def __get__(self,obj,cls):

        def returned(*args):
            print(obj.__dict__)
        return types.MethodType(returned, obj, cls)
```

However, it's not totally clear what this gains you.  If just returning a function already works, why do you need it to be a "real" method?

Comment: With the changes, when I call f.e (f is instance of class F which has e as an attribute, e is instance of E), it's giving error TypeError: method expected 2 arguments, got 3.

Comment: I am using Python3.3, could that be the reason

Comment: This is perfect (at least in Python 2.7) I see that the returned object's im_self and im_func are set properly. Would you know how to do it in 3.3